# selective search in cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning

I am learning R-CNN, the first step for R-CNN is selective search, I used this algorithm on a sample image from my dataset.

Code -

```
ss = cv2.ximgproc.segmentation.createSelectiveSearchSegmentation()
ss.setBaseImage(image)
ss.switchToSelectiveSearchFast()
rects = ss.process()
```

I got more than 6000 proposals. How to minimize the proposals where I have few objects?

Comment: You can refer to [this blog](https://www.learnopencv.com/selective-search-for-object-detection-cpp-python/).

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your results (6000 proposals) you can then enumerate through a specified number you set. You can see an implementation [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/step-by-step-r-cnn-implementation-from-scratch-in-python-e97101ccde55).

Answer (score 0):

Do a processing step. Like remove all those whose bboxes area is smaller. So that now you're left with the remaining bboxes. Likewise there are some methods to process the region proposals from Selective Search.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate in the list of regions that you got from selective search and only consider the regions which have an area between some specific amounts.

For example, if the area of a region is:

-already a candidate (duplicate)

-less than 5% of the image's area (too small)

-more than 100% of the image's area  (too big)

then you can skip that candidate and this leaves only with the significant candidates.